# Word Or Expression For "This is background information you should know first"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm trying to write something at work that's broken into sections. One sub-section is just about background information that aids in understanding the subsequent sections to follow. I could label it "Background Information", but I was wondering if there's a better word or expression?

I've had "precursor" and "preamble" suggested to me, but I'm not sure those convey the sense of being about information useful to understanding what comes next. "Synopsis" was also suggested to me, but this too doesn't seem to fit.

Comment: Have you tried searching for synonyms of "fundamentals."

Comment: Underpinnings, groundwork, Nitty-gritty, brass tacks, elementals, fundamentals, rudiments, abcd, backbone...

Comment: Re. the title: *required reading*.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with titling the section Background.

Answer (score 2):

**"introductory foundation"** may fit well.

> - foundation -  the basis or groundwork of anything, that on which something is founded; basis. [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/foundation)

e.g. "My ultimate goal is to provide the reader both a solid [**introductory foundation**](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=SioWBAAAQBAJ&pg=RA1-PR4&dq=%22introductory+foundation%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj7kbHhy_vMAhULjZAKHU7ABXoQ6AEIPDAE#v=onepage&q=%22introductory%20foundation%22&f=false) and a connection to the literature,

or [**"the basics"**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/basics) -  a statement of fundamental facts or principles, 
rudiments.

Answer (score 1):

"Background information that aids in understanding the subsequent sections to follow," might be found in the **glossary**, **index** or **appendix** *of* the introduction. Normally these would be found at the end of a work, but it's not uncommon to have, e.g., *'Appendix `A`, page XVII'* listed in the contents, which is still part of the introduction.

> [glossary](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/glossary) :
>
> 1. a list of terms in a special subject, field, or area of usage, with accompanying definitions.
> 2. such a list at the back of a book, explaining or defining difficult or unusual words and expressions used in the text.
>
> [index](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/index?s=ts) :
>
> 1. (in a nonfiction book, monograph, etc.) a more or less detailed alphabetical listing of names, places, and topics along with the numbers of the pages on which they are mentioned or discussed, usually included in or constituting the back matter.
>
> [appendix](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/appendix?s=t) :
>
> 1. supplementary material at the end of a book, article, document, or other text, usually of an explanatory, statistical, or bibliographic nature.
>
> –dictionary.com

---

[**Back Matter**: Appendices, Glossaries and More](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Professional_and_Technical_Writing/Design/Back_Matter) –en.wikibooks.org (excerpt)

**Back Matter** is an important part of a professional business document, and any other long document. It may contain one or more of the following: **appendices, bibliography, works cited, reference list, end notes, glossary, list of symbols, or indices**.

These elements are used for citing sources, giving definitions to uncommon words, and giving the reader a list of topics and where they are in the document. All may not be read by every reader, but they are still important parts to include. Back Matter is for the reader that wants to know more. You may decide to add more or less to a document depending on the situation.

How back matter strengthens a document:

- Guides readers to the information they need
- Expands on the information in the document
- Leads readers to other documents on the topic

---

A "precursor" or a "preamble" would be found in the *introduction*, using whichever of these words (and more) to further identify it. E.g., *Appendix `C` : Important Safety Information.*

A "synopsis" is akin to an *abstract*. I agree that these don't fit; they're both 'cliff notes'.

I don't know the term for *'Roman-numbering'* the introduction but it's always, "information useful to understanding what comes next," that you can skip if you're familiar with the topic.

Comment: I'd never heard of *Back Matter* before today. I prefer *Glossary of Terms* or 'appendices'. Don't get me started on what happened to always including an index...